# SQLite3 Closing Connection right before commiting in Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm using Flask to build a web app.I'm using sqlite3 to store information.
SCHEMA is as follows :

- TABLES AND FIELDS:
- User: id,name,password,email,phone,address
- Ptype: id,value
- Status:id,value
- Product:id,name,price,ptype_id,stock ( ptype_id references the id of Ptype )
- Cart:id,uid,status_id (status_id references the id of Status )
- Order:id,uid,cart_id,o_total,date,status_id  (uid references id of User,Cart_id references the id of Cart,status_id references the id of Status)
- Cart_item:index,cart_id,p_id,quantity,p_total (cart_id references the id of Cart,p_id references the id of Product)

I have a form which takes the input "quantity" and inserts a record to the Cart_items table.
The Insertion doesn't give any exception.But right after Inserting,The "g.db.commit()" is giving a "Cannot operate on a closed database" Exception. So,I can't even commit my changes to the database.
The relevant functions used are given below. User is a class. I'm using sessions to store the details of the logged in user. CurrentUser() returns the details of the logged in User in dictionary format.
CurrentCart_id() returns the id of the cart of Currently Logged in user.If there is none,It will insert a value to the database and return that value.

I have a feeling that CurrentCart_id() is unintentionally closing the database connection. If so,How do I avoid that? Isn't it a good practice to close the database after inserting a value?
If any other section of the code/ any more explanation is needed,I will be happy to provide them..
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect('users.db')
```

```
g.db = connect_db()
g.db.execute('INSERT INTO Cart_Items(cart_id,p_id,quantity,p_total) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[(CurrentCart_id()[0][0]),pid,int(request.form['quantity']),ptotal])
g.db.commit()
g.db.close()
```

```
def CurrentCart_id():
    g.db = connect_db()
    try:
        cursor = g.db.execute('SELECT id FROM Cart WHERE (uid=? AND status_id=1);',[CurrentUser()['id']])
        cart_id=cursor.fetchall()
        if(len(cart_id)==0):
            g.db.execute("INSERT INTO Cart (uid,status_id) VALUES(?,1);",[CurrentUser()['id']])
            cursor = g.db.execute('SELECT id FROM Cart WHERE (uid=? AND status_id=1);',[CurrentUser()['id']])
            cart_id=cursor.fetchall()
        g.db.commit()
        g.db.close()
        return cart_id
    except:
        g.db.rollback()
        g.db.close()
        return ("No User Logged in!")
```

```
def CurrentUser():
    try:
        if session['User']:
            return session['User']
    except:
        return EmptyUser()
```

```
def EmptyUser():
    return User(None,None,None,None,None,None).__dict__
```

```
class User:
    def __init__(self,id,name,password,email,phone,address):
        self.id=id
        self.name=name
        self.password=password
        self.email=email
        self.phone=phone
        self.address=address
```

Comment: sqlite is not a good choice for multi-user access (implied by using flask). If I was you, I would separate the life cycle of the connection from the operations you perform, for instance, if you run two queries it would be preferable to use the same connection.

Comment: In the first insert statement have you tried using a duple rather than an array?  And in the 2nd insert try using a tuple again... remember the format is (value,)

Comment: I fixed this issue by removing the g.db.close() inside the CurrentCart_id() function and declaring a new variable 'arg' to hold the parameters to be passed to the Insert Statement. I still didn't get why it didn't work just by removing the g.db.close() inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

So,I fixed the issue by removing the g.db.close() inside the CurrentCart_id() and by passing the parameters by using a newly declared variable "args" as follows :

```
g.db = connect_db()
args=[int(CurrentCart_id()[0][0]),pid,int(request.form['quantity']),ptotal]
g.db.execute('INSERT INTO Cart_Items(cart_id,p_id,quantity,p_total) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',args)
g.db.commit()
g.db.close()
```

The new CurrentCart_id() looks like :

```
def CurrentCart_id():
    g.db = connect_db()
    try:
        cursor = g.db.execute('SELECT id FROM Cart WHERE (uid=? AND status_id=1);',[CurrentUser()['id']])
        cart_id=cursor.fetchall()
        if(len(cart_id)==0):
            g.db.execute("INSERT INTO Cart (uid,status_id) VALUES(?,1);",[CurrentUser()['id']])
            cursor = g.db.execute('SELECT id FROM Cart WHERE (uid=? AND status_id=1);',[CurrentUser()['id']])
            cart_id=cursor.fetchall()
        g.db.commit()
        return cart_id
    except:
        g.db.rollback()
        g.db.close()
        return ("No User Logged in!")
```

I don't really know or understand why this worked. If anyone knows why this worked or this might not work and cause problems later,Please do respond.